# softirq -- how far in network stack does it last?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, interrupt-handling, softirq

I've been studying about `interrupts` in Linux and `softirq` in particular (I'm interested in networking subsystem of the kernel). I understand the concept of top-half and bottom-half, but what's not clear to me is -- how far does the `softirq` context last? Until what point in the kernel stack we deal with `softirq`? For example, when the ingress path hits `ip_rcv()`, are we still in soft interrupt mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rudely speaking, softirq context lasts until the softirq-handler returns.

> ip_rcv(), are we still in soft interrupt mode

Yep, we are in softirq context. We're inside [call-stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) of function, that was raised as `NET_RX_SOFTIRQ`.

Let's talk about receive path considering NAPI.
[`____napi_schedule()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/net/core/dev.c#L3268) raises `NET_RX_SOFTIRQ` (it in turn modifies per-CPU data structure by accessing `irq_stat.__softirq_pending`). Then the softirq handler moves packet up to the stack. All these actions are in softirq context. So here are two different directions: 1) this is forward packet - so the softirq context lasts until this packet will be added to some output queue and the handler will return. 2) this is local input packet - so the softirq lasts until this packet will be added (enqueued) to local socket receive queue, after which the handler returns. Such things are in case of dropping anywhere in the network stack. It all terminates when the basic softirq-function/handler terminates.